# How do I transfer variables between modules in Python?

Tags: python, module

mod.py:

```
def addone(number):
    result = number + 1
```

test.py:

```
import mod

print mod.addone(2)
```

The result I get is `None`, so I am guessing the result variable is missing. What is missing from my code.

And yes, I know this can easily be done without a module, it's just an example.

Comment: You're missing a `return`: `return number + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the import right, the method in mod.py that is not returning the result. Change to:

```
def addone(number):
    return number + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

'return' is missing in add_one, so you got None